# APNS stops working each time I put out a new ad-hoc release

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, push

Have development certificate, set up all code on server, it works great!

Generate new release, distribute as ad-hoc, put on TestFlight, pushes stop working every time.

The only thing I've found to return functionality is to rebuild the code on the server each time, and turn on and off all the notification settings for the app in the device settings, but even then that doesn't always work right and suddenly it will just start working (seemingly 24+ hours after pulling my hair out).

Comment: I'm assuming you know that AdHoc build works with production ANPS environment (requires production provisioning profile and using a production certificate at your server to send messages).

Comment: Turns out, when I switched from Development to Production, I didn't reset the apns server from the apns Sandbox server. embarrassing. thanks for your help, it made me go back and rethink everything.